# PHP - Regex deletes one character too much

Tags: php, regex

I can't found out how to solve the following problem:

```
 preg_replace("/e[^t]/", "", "testet");
```

This shall cut out just the 'e', but it deletes 'es'. How can I achieve it that it only deletes the first e (and leaves the second one 'et' out)?

Thanks!

Comment: What string do you want?  `teetet` or `testet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative lookaheads:

```
preg_replace("/e(?!t)/", "", "testet")
```

As explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) lookaheads don't capture characters (consume characters) they only assert if the match would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/e([^t])/", "$1", "testet");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/e[^t]/` try with `/e(?!t)/` (Negative lookaheads)

Answer (score -3):

Make it un-greedy

```
preg_replace("/e[^t]/u", "", "testet");
```

Comment: Problem has nothing to do with greediness, as there are no wildcards in the pattern.